# Ruby on rails and AngularJs - How to bound to each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, devise

So I created a Ruby on Rails API, and I added all my JS file into app/assets.

The only thing I am struggling with is security and authentication. To handle this I tried to use Devise-token-auth and Ng-Token-Auth but it was a horrible nightmare and I couldn't make it work. Is there another easier way to manage this?

Thank you so much.